# Examples of uniformly convex spaces which are not of any power type

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $(X, \Vert\cdot\Vert)$ be a Banach space and let $S_X$ denote the unit sphere. The modulus of convexity of a norm $\Vert\cdot\Vert$ on $X$ is defined for $\epsilon\in[0,2]$ by $$\delta_{\Vert\cdot\Vert}(\epsilon)=\inf\left\{ 1-\frac{1}{2}\Vert x+y\Vert\,\colon\,x,y\in S_X\,,\,\Vert x-y\Vert\geq\epsilon\right\}.$$ The space $(X, \Vert\cdot\Vert)$ is called uniformly convex if $\delta_{\Vert\cdot\Vert}(\epsilon)>0$ for all $\epsilon\in(0,2]$. Additionally, we say that $(X, \Vert\cdot\Vert)$ has modulus of convexity of power type $p\geq2$ (or simply that the space is $p$-convex) if there exists $\beta>0$ such that $\delta_{\Vert\cdot\Vert}(\epsilon)\geq\beta\epsilon^p$ for $\epsilon\in[0,2]$.

Every uniformly convex Banach space is reflexive (Milman–Pettis theorem). In functional analysis books, these definitions are frequently used to show that the $L^r(\Omega)$ spaces are reflexivy for $r\in(1,\infty)$. That is, they show that $L^r(\Omega)$ is uniformly convex and then apply the Milman–Pettis theorem.

Other examples of uniformly convex spaces are every Hilbert spaces. But $L^r(\Omega)$ is a $\text{max}\{r,2\}$-convex space and Hilbert spaces are $2$-convex spaces. I don't know any example of a space $X$ that is uniformly convex, but it isn't $p$-convex. Can someone please provide examples of such spaces?